# Change long click delay

Tags: android, view

I am listening for a View's long click events via setOnLongClickListener(). Can I change the long click delay / duration?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

AFAIK, no. It is hard-wired in the framework via `getLongPressTimeout()` on `ViewConfiguration`.

You are welcome to handle your own touch events and define your own "long click" concept. Just be sure that it is not too dramatically different from what the user expects, and most likely the user will expect what all the other apps use, which is the standard 500ms duration.

Comment: How would you go about defining your own long click concept?

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will stick with the default for now.

Comment: @zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz probably by overriding View. Cool username BTW ;-)

Answer (score 25):

This is my way for set duration to long press

```
private int longClickDuration = 3000;
private boolean isLongPress = false;

numEquipeCheat.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                isLongPress = true;
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (isLongPress) {
                            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            vibrator.vibrate(100);
                            // set your code here
                            // Don't forgot to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> to vibrate.
                        }
                    }
                }, longClickDuration);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                isLongPress = false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 20):

I defined an extension function  in **Kotlin** inspired by @Galoway answer:

```
fun View.setOnVeryLongClickListener(listener: () -> Unit) {
    setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {

        private val longClickDuration = 2000L
        private val handler = Handler()

        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                handler.postDelayed({ listener.invoke() }, longClickDuration)
            } else if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
            }
            return true
        }
    })
}
```

Use it like this:

```
button.setOnVeryLongClickListener {
    // Do something here
}
```

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Krasvcheg, horoshee reshenie.

Comment: I suggest you add
performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS)
before listener.invoke() to add the same haptic feedback as in case of system long click event.

Answer (score 7):

This is what I use. It is similar to Cumulo Nimbus' answer, with two notable differences.

1. Use the already stored event values for down time and current time. Aside from not duplicating effort, this has the nice effect of making the listener usable for multiple views at the same time without tracking start times for each individual event.
2. Check `view.isPressed` to ensure the user has not moved away from the view during the touch event. This mimics the default system behavior for `onClick` and `onLongClick`.

---

```
long longPressTimeout = 2000;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (view.isPressed() && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        long eventDuration = event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime();
        if (eventDuration > longPressTimeout) {
            onLongClick(view);
        } else {
            onClick(view);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

If the view is not normally clickable you will need to call `view.setClickable(true)` for the `view.isPressed()` check to work.

Comment: Simple and elegant!

Answer (score 6):

This was the simplest working solution I found to this restriction:

```
//Define these variables at the beginning of your Activity or Fragment:
private long then;
private int longClickDuration = 5000; //for long click to trigger after 5 seconds

...

//This can be a Button, TextView, LinearLayout, etc. if desired
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.desired_longclick_view);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          then = (long) System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - then) > longClickDuration) {
            /* Implement long click behavior here */
            System.out.println("Long Click has happened!");
            return false;
          } else {
            /* Implement short click behavior here or do nothing */
            System.out.println("Short Click has happened...");
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for handeling both onclick and custom long click on same button

```
public static final int LONG_PRESS_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_save:
            saveInfo();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_save:
            initSendInfo(v, System.currentTimeMillis());
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}

private void initSendInfo(final View v, final long startTime) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (v.isPressed() && System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= LONG_PRESS_DELAY_MILLIS) {
                sendInfo();
                return;
            } else if (!v.isPressed()) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }, LONG_PRESS_DELAY_MILLIS);

}
```

Comment: This works fine! To make the v and startTime accessible in the run method, they must be declared final
private void initSendInfo(final View v, final long startTime) { ... }

Comment: Edit: For initSendInfo method, added final keyword for arguments, as per Lipsyor's comments. Thanyou Lipsyor.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me on `API 29`, while retaining the button's visual down state using **Kotlin**:

```
fun AppCompatButton.setOnVeryLongClickListener(
  holdDuration: Long = 1000L, 
  listener: () -> Unit
) {
    val handler = Handler()
    val originalText = this.text

    setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // update the copy of the button
            text = "$originalText (KEEP HOLDING)"

            // fire the listener after our hold duration
            handler.postDelayed({ listener.invoke() }, holdDuration)
        } else if(event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // update the copy of the button
            text = "$originalText (TAP & HOLD)"

            // in case of an interruption, cancel everything
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
        }

        // return false in order to retain the button's visual down state
        false
    }
}

button.setOnVeryLongClickListener {
    println("very long!")
}
```