# Detect gesture few second like iOS

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to add a gesture to my recyclerview, which detect a click of 5 seconds and that after 5 seconds it executes a method.

On iOS, in Swift, here is my code:

```
func setupLongPressGesture() {
    let longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
    longPressGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    usersTableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}

@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

    displayProfile = false;
    navItemSelected.isHidden = false; //La nav du bas

    //On le programme en .began pour executer la methode meme si le doight est encore sur l'ecran. Le .end c'est quand le doight s'enleve de l'ecran
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.usersTableView)

        if let indexPath = usersTableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint)?.row {
            ViewController.selectedUsers.append(users[indexPath]);
            countSelected.text = "(\(ViewController.selectedUsers.count))";
        }
    }

    usersTableView.reloadData()
}
```

I want the same for Android.

Comment: yes my friend..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change long click delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958418/change-long-click-delay)

Comment: it's not good because it only executes the method if the finger is removed from the screen..